# No Wi-Fi adapter found on Lenovo V570c with AR9285 running Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, adapter

I performed a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on my Lenovo V570c and there is no Wi-Fi adapter right from the start.

The terminal shows:

[image: network DISABLED]

I checked the BIOS and Wi-Fi is enabled. Ubuntu 20.04.3 is the only operating system on this PC. If this information is not enough, please ask for more.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `rfkill list` terminal command. Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: By posting a picture of text, you make it impossible for potential helpers on phones, or text terminals. to see your text. You make it impossible for any of us to make a local copy for investigation. Rather, [Edit] your Question, copy and paste the text into your Question, select it and use the `{}` formatting tool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)